# Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`

Tags: npm, sass, autoprefixer, web-compiler

Recently, when I compile my scss files I get an error. The error message says:

> Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`

First, as the message says, I ran `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist` but it didn't fix the issue.
I deleted the whole node_modules directory and installed again, also I updated the whole folder by `npm update` but none of them solved the issue.
I also reinstalled autoprefixer and browserslist but none of them solved the issue.

If I remove

```
"options": {
      "autoPrefix": "> 1%"
    }
```

from my `compilerconfig.json`, everything works fine which means probably it is related to autoprefixer. Also, I manually changed the package version to the latest version on `package.json` and reinstalled but no luck.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It sounds like you are using Visual Studio's Web Compiler extension.  There is an open issue for this found here: https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler/issues/413

There is a workaround posted in that issue:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Head to `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\WebCompilerX.X.X` (X is the version of WebCompiler)
3. Delete following folders from `node_modules` folder: `caniuse-lite` and `browserslist`
   Open up CMD (inside `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\WebCompilerX.X.X`) and run: `npm i caniuse-lite browserslist`

Comment: I did it and I don't have that error anymore but I got a new error: Plugin Error: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'. I tried to reinstall and updating autoprefixer but I still get that error.

Comment: Sounds like a different issue.  If you have a link to your project online or can put together another project that has the problem, I would be happy to look at it.

Comment: It seems when I was trying to fix the issue by upgrading and reinstalling autoprefixer I had broken something. Luckily, today Web Compiler updated itself and I saw that error message again. I followed the steps above and this time the issue fixed.

Comment: Any idea where  this directory is on the mac?

Comment: If I follow these directions, I get `added 2 packages, removed 677 packages, and changed 3 packages in 14s` and then WebCompiler fails entirely with `"C:\Users\[Me]\AppData\Local\Temp\WebCompiler1.14.11\node_modules\.bin\sass.cmd"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I have to delete the whole "WebCompiler1.14.11" folder and restart Visual Studio to get everything back.

Answer (score 220):

Try this it solved my problem `npx browserslist@latest --update-db`

Comment: For context: My IDE is VS Code, and my JS project only included Parcel, react, and react-dom when I began seeing this error.  None of the above options worked.  This solution fixed mine.

Comment: Fails on Windows
```
C:\projects\ember-cli-typescript-blueprints>npx browserslist@latest --update-db
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     c:\npm\cache\_logs\2020-11-15T14_19_08_958Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'browserslist@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

Comment: What is `npx`? How is it different than `npm`?

Comment: @Marquizzo `npx` is a way to directly execute npm package, without saving it on your system.

Comment: The source of explanation is in the Browsers Data Updating section on browserlist npm homepage: https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserslist

Comment: Some info on what ```--update-db ``` does: 

Updates the caniuse-lite database with browsers. With all data last 2 versions or >1% will return old browsers and Autoprefixer/Babel will insert polyfills for browsers, which nobody really uses nowadays.

Another option will be to run npm update, but it will update all your dependencies, which will force you to run the full QA process.

Comment: Awesome bhai. I was facing 2 other issues but you solved all of then in one go. :-) However there is only a small difference of `@latest` but your answer has solved this problem also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155525/browserslisterror-unknown-version-67-of-android

Comment: I ran this command which is recommended by nx.  Now all of my npm scripts are exiting with `Unknown version 62 of op_mob`.   Has anyone gotten this error back?

Comment: Note that this is not just for NPM! This command works with Yarn as well. Pulling from their readme:  `updates caniuse-lite version in your npm, yarn or pnpm lock file.`

Comment: Where do I run this command, when I just run it in the root it says that package.json cannot be found.

Comment: When I ran `npx browserslist@latest --update-db` it seemed to work but it also stated that the `--update-db` command is deprecated.  It said to use `npx update-browserslist-db@latest` instead.

Answer (score 54):

Many advise you to remove the `package-lock.json` or the `yarn.lock`. This is clearly a bad idea!

I am using Yarn and I was able to correct this problem by removing only the `caniuse-db` and `caniuse-lite` entries in my `yarn.lock` and doing a `yarn`.

It is not necessary to break the main function of the lockfile by deleting it.

Comment: Same. I did not have `caniuse-db` in `yarn.lock`, but I had two entries for `caniuse-lite`. Removed both of them and then `yarn install`ed again. Worked like a charm.

Comment: This is the only way if all other methods failed. I was stuck in this for hours, thank you for this

Comment: I also had to remove `browserslist` form `yarn.lock`.

Comment: Since it was a fresh project, deleting `yarn.lock `wasn't an issue.

Comment: @Frizzant On a fresh project you don't need to update caniuse

Answer (score 49):

## Simple, safe solution

The answer from @Alexandr Nil is safe, and was effective for me. I am writing as a full answer because it is easy to miss his comment.

```
npm --depth 20 update --save caniuse-lite browserslist
```

This is good because:

1. There is no deletion of `package-lock.json`. Deleting that would leave you vulnerable to many packages getting upgraded with breaking changes, and you have a much bigger headache than you had before!
2. It is easy to understand exactly what it is doing, because it is explicit and very limited on what is to be updated.
3. It avoids the very large depth of 99 or 9999 which will work on some projects and systems, but not on others. If you have limited the depth to too small a number, it will not break anything. You can increase the depth and try again, until the project compiles successfully. I don't know whether I actually needed 20, or could have managed with a smaller depth, such as 5 or 10. But with a depth of 20 took less than a minute to run.
4. It is quick and easy!

Thank you to @Zbyszek for suggesting to add the "--save" option. And yes, --depth is currently deprecated, but I assume they will replace it with something else rather than entirely remove it, so for now this seems to be the least destructive approach.

Thank you to @pipedreambomb for pointing out that it might seem to just hang. If that happens, try running it with smaller numbers and working upwards:

```
npm --depth 1 update --save caniuse-lite browserslist 

npm --depth 2 update --save caniuse-lite browserslist 

(etc)
```

Comment: Currently --depth is deprecated and simply does not affect how the update works. See implemented [RFC0019](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0019-remove-update-depth-option.md). Also might need to add --save in some circumstances like local node_modules folder. Otherwise - good answer, I like this way more than deleting folders (which may become a bad way to do that).

Comment: Perhaps this is out of date, as it just seems to lock my terminal. I've waited 5 minutes and it hasn't even output anything.

Comment: Just tried running it now, and it works fine. Perhaps try with a very small `--depth` and work upwards?

Comment: It seems like this no longer works, it says that --depth no longer has any effect.

Comment: There is indeed a warn message "The --depth option no longer has any effect. See RFC0019", but the command still works and does the trick.

Answer (score 35):

### For Angular Developers

Although, I'm answering this very late. I have a bad habit of checking changelogs of every library I use  and while checking the release notes of Angular CLI, I figured out that they released a new patch yesterday (9th Jan 2020) which fixes this issue.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v8.3.22

So when you will run `ng update`, you should get updates for `@angular/cli`:

[image]

And running `ng update @angular/cli` will fix this warning.

Cheers!

Answer (score 22):

I found a short cut rather than going through `vs code appData/webCompiler`, I added it as a dependency to my project **with this cmd** `npm i caniuse-lite browserslist`. But you might install it globally to avoid adding it to each project.

After installation, you could remove it from your project `package.json` and do `npm i`.

Update:

In case, Above solution didn't fix it. You could run `npm update`, as this would upgrade deprecated/outdated packages.

Note:

After you've run the npm update, there may be missing dependencies. Trace the error and install the missing dependencies. Mine was nodemon, which I fix by `npm i nodemon -g`

Comment: I didn't have the /WebCompiler folder in my /TEMP folder like some other posts here suggested, so I ran this command line and it seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 16):

Continuation of [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55283201/37796).

Had the same "plugin error" as @MehrdadBabaki.  I uninstalled web compiler, deleted the AppData WebCompiler folder mentioned above, then reopened VS2019 and reinstalled web compiler.

THEN I went to the WebCompiler folder again and did `npm i autoprefixer@latest` `npm i caniuse-lite@latest` and `npm i caniuse-lite browserslist@latest`

Comment: just update autoprefixer, caniuse-lite, browserslist is good for me

Answer (score 14):

There is an environment variable >= 4.5.4, `BROWSERSLIST_IGNORE_OLD_DATA`, that you can set truthy to suppress the warning (`BROWSERSLIST_IGNORE_OLD_DATA=true`). See commit [Add BROWSERSLIST_IGNORE_OLD_DATA environment variable](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/commit/0ae7155a6c7d8f58eaeb3ea450c21bec76de2763).

Here's a snippet of the relevant code from that commit showing the early bailout upon checking this environment variable:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  oldDataWarning: function oldDataWarning (agentsObj) {
    if (dataTimeChecked) return
    dataTimeChecked = true
    if (process.env.BROWSERSLIST_IGNORE_OLD_DATA) return

    // ...
    console.warn(
      'Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. ' +
      'Please run next command `' + command + '`'
    )
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 12):

`npm --depth 9999 update` fixed the issue for me--apparently because `package-lock.json` was insisting on the outdated versions.

Comment: Even `npm --depth 99 update caniuse-lite browserslist` caused `JavaScript heap out of memory` in my project, but `npm --depth 20 update caniuse-lite browserslist` run fast and solved the error in my case.

Comment: `--depth` flag is deprecated - [reference](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0019-remove-update-depth-option.md)

Comment: @AlexandrNil Thank you bro it solved the issue for me!

Comment: I am getting a unknown version 62 of op_mob.  Wondering if this is part of the issue.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I deleted out the `caniuse-lite`, `browserslist` folders from `node_modules`.

Then I type the following command to install the packages.

```
npm i -g browserslist caniuse-lite --save
```

worked fine.

Comment: We had to add `npm i browserslist caniuse-lite --save`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in Scott Kuhl's answer this issue is mentioned in
https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler/issues/413

For me, running the command `npm i caniuse-lite- browserslist` only worked for about 1/2 a day before it was an issue again.

The following solution, mentioned in the post, works much better. This updates the node.js file so that it uses `console.log` instead of `console.warn` when returning these errors.

You can manually update this file located at 
C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Temp\WebCompiler[VersionNumber]\node_modules\browserslist

Or, so that it is done automatically, add the following to your .csproj file by:

1. Right click on project file and select "Unload Project"
2. Edit the .csproj file
3. Paste the following into the project file. I pasted it towards the end of the file, before the `</Project>` end tag and before the build web compiler package was imported.

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="MSBuildTasks" Version="1.5.0.235">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TempFolder>$([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath())</TempFolder>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <BrowsersListNodeJsFiles Include="$(TempFolder)\WebCompiler*\node_modules\browserslist\node.js" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="BrowsersListWarningsAsInfo" BeforeTargets="WebCompile">
        <FileUpdate Files="@(BrowsersListNodeJsFiles)"
                    Regex="console.warn"
                    ReplacementText="console.log" />
    </Target>
```

4. Reload the project back into the solution.

Comment: Thank you! This was the best fix for me. The above fixes would get outdated every other day!

Answer (score 2):

## My Issue solved by doing this in my react native project

npx browserslist@latest --update-db

#### console ->

```
Latest version:     1.0.30001363
Installed version:  1.0.30001296
Removing old caniuse-lite from lock file
Installing new caniuse-lite version
$ npm install caniuse-lite
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
Cleaning package.json dependencies from caniuse-lite
$ npm uninstall caniuse-lite
caniuse-lite has been successfully updated

Target browser changes:
- and_chr 96
+ and_chr 103
- and_ff 95
+ and_ff 101
- android 96
+ android 103
- chrome 96
- chrome 95
- chrome 94
+ chrome 103
+ chrome 102
+ chrome 101
- edge 96
- edge 95
+ edge 103
+ edge 102
- firefox 95
- firefox 94
+ firefox 102
+ firefox 101
- ios_saf 15.2
- ios_saf 15.0-15.1
+ ios_saf 15.5
+ ios_saf 15.4
+ ios_saf 15.2-15.3
- opera 82
- opera 81
+ opera 87
+ opera 86
+ opera 85
- safari 15.2
- safari 15.1
- safari 13.1
+ safari 15.5
+ safari 15.4
- samsung 15.0
- samsung 14.0
+ samsung 17.0
+ samsung 16.0
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly for me with webpack & bud.js v6.7.0 to get a clean console again.

Answer (score 2):

If you use pnpm, you can bump the `caniuse-lite` entries of the lock file by doing:

```bash
pnpm install autoprefixer@latest caniuse-lite@latest browserslist@latest
```

Then remove them from `package.json#dependencies`.

I'd assume it works with other package manager as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem too this command works for me

`npm i autoprefixer@latest`

It automatically added need dependency in `package.json` and `package-lock.json` file like below:

**package.json**

```
"autoprefixer": "^9.6.5",
```

**package-lock.json**

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": {

...

"dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": {
      "version": "9.4.6",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/autoprefixer/-/autoprefixer-9.4.6.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Yp51mevbOEdxDUy5WjiKtpQaecqYq9OqZSL04rSoCiry7Tc5I9FEyo3bfxiTJc1DfHeKwSFCUYbBAiOQ2VGfiw==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "browserslist": "^4.4.1",
        "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30000929",
        "normalize-range": "^0.1.2",
        "num2fraction": "^1.2.2",
        "postcss": "^7.0.13",
        "postcss-value-parser": "^3.3.1"
      }
    },

...

  }

...

"autoprefixer": {
    "version": "9.6.5",
    "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/autoprefixer/-/autoprefixer-9.6.5.tgz",
    "integrity": "sha512-rGd50YV8LgwFQ2WQp4XzOTG69u1qQsXn0amww7tjqV5jJuNazgFKYEVItEBngyyvVITKOg20zr2V+9VsrXJQ2g==",
    "requires": {
      "browserslist": "^4.7.0",
      "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30000999",
      "chalk": "^2.4.2",
      "normalize-range": "^0.1.2",
      "num2fraction": "^1.2.2",
      "postcss": "^7.0.18",
      "postcss-value-parser": "^4.0.2"
    },

...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete package.lock.json File then go to node_modules folder and delete     caniuse-lite,     browserslist    Then run     `ng update @angular/cli`     and also run      `npm i caniuse-lite- browserslist`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure where my problem was, but I believe it was because I was using the same global packages from both npm and Yarn.

I uninstalled all the npm global packages, then when using yarn commands once again, the problem was gone.

To see global packages installed...

for npm:

```
npm ls -g --depth=0
```

for Yarn:

```
yarn global list
```

I then uninstalled each package I saw in the npm listing, using:

```
npm uninstall -g <package-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case I have to manually execute `pnpm up caniuse-lite`.

Answer (score -1):

I did downgrade the node version from 12 to 10

EDIT

This error occurred with me because I was using node version 12.
When I downgrade to version 10.16.5 this error stops. This error happened in my local env, but in prod and staging, it not happens. In prod and staging node version is 10.x so I just do this and I didn't need to update any package in my package.json

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer, even if it is right, try to explain a little bit.

Comment: It is not a bad answer... just edit it a little bit and done.

Answer (score -1):

Deleting node_modules and reinstalling (npm i) worked for me. Did not delete package-lock.json.

Answer (score -2):

## Minimal solution that worked for me for current project

- A create-react-app project
- Ubuntu / *nix
- 2020
- Node 14.7

delete `node_modules/browserslist` directory in the project

now

```
npm run build
```

no longer generates that message

Comment: If you just deleted the directory, what happens next time you `npm install`/`npm ci`?

Comment: actualy i then ran into an issue with css perfix, finally I updated create-create-app for that project and all was good.

Answer (score -2):

The thing that worked for me is to first build the project like

> npm run build

then run it like

> npm run start

this will disappear error and application loading fine.

Answer (score -2):

For me it was just as simple as turning off my VPN. I was using ExpressVPN and onced I turned it off 'npm start' command was working fine without getting this error. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

Deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and `npm i` solve the issue for me.

Comment: deleting package-lock.json could result to some breaking changes error if you have a long history of package installation, for example a project that was working and developed for more than a year and have packages that has a lot of 3rd level dependency could make breaking changes

Answer (score -3):

I've fixed this issue by doing, step by step:

1. remove `node_modules`
2. remove `package-lock.json`,
3. run `npm --depth 9999 update`
4. run `npm install`

Comment: Be careful with removing `package-lock.json` as it could introduce breaking changes and should be avoided.

Answer (score -4):

This worked for me:

> 'npm -g update'

Answer (score -4):

The below steps worked for me

1. `rm -rf node_modules/`
2. `yarn`
3. `yarn upgrade caniuse-lite browserlist`
4. restarting server & clear browser cache.

Answer (score -5):

If you use yarn:

```
yarn upgrade
```

Help for me