# How do I fix 'Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated' for my Vue build?

Tags: vue.js, babeljs

When doing a vue-cli build through npm I get this error:

```
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`
```

This was working until recently and I'm not sure what would cause this to start failing. Seems like some timeframe hit that made it start reporting as 'outdated' but I don't know what to update to fix it.

I have tried running the suggested command but it doesn't do the trick. I am doing this through npm and am not using Visual Studio, so I am not using WebCompiler (and that directory doesn't exist in my user folder) so the solution in [Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271798/browserslist-caniuse-lite-is-outdated-please-run-next-command-npm-update-cani) doesn't apply.

This also happens on our build system running through VSO, so it isn't just my box.

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "productName.portal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "productName.portal static content",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "keywords": [
    "gulp",
    "task"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.1.4",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.4",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.8",
    "@voerro/vue-tagsinput": "^1.8.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0-rc.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.0.0-rc.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.0.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "3.0.0-rc.4",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.20",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "latest",
    "gulp-concat": "latest",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "latest",
    "gulp-uglify": "latest",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^23.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-js-modal": "^1.3.16",
    "vue-loading-overlay": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-simple-spinner": "^1.2.8",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-toasted": "^1.1.24",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.5.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node": "^9.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1",
    "trie-search": "^1.2.8",
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-class-component": "^6.0.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^7.0.0",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "unittest": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  }
}
```

Comment: I ended up removing my node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file and doing an npm install then an npm update for good measure, but for some reason the browserlist module is now not being put into the node_modules folder. I did an explicit ```npm update caniuse-lite browserslist``` which forced the latest version of these node modules to install and that actually seems to have done the trick. I tried this on a fresh working copy and it seems like a viable solution. I think the problem stems form another packages reference somehow, but by explicitly installing them, it fixed it.

Comment: @Phil had a better solution - the above comment is a workaround if you can't find the culprit, but the answer below actually seems to be the solution to my problem!

Answer (score 14):

This is all down to the dependencies of `@babel/preset-env`

```
├─┬ @babel/preset-env
│ ├─┬ browserslist
│ │ ├── caniuse-lite
```

You can rectify this by updating that package

```sh
npm update @babel/preset-env
```

---

Just realised that Vue uses a few more levels of dependency

```
├─┬ @vue/cli-plugin-babel
│ ├─┬ @vue/babel-preset-app
│ │ ├─┬ @babel/preset-env
```

so you'll want to update the `@vue/cli-plugin-babel` package.

Comment: Hmm, seems it was a combination with the first suggestion to delete the package-lock.json and this one that had fixed it before. I reverted my package-lock.json file and just did those two suggestions and it does not fix it. Seems like something else must also be causing issues...I don't know, something still doesn't seem right.

Comment: Updating `@babel/preset-env` was the solution for a React project as well. Thanks for posting!