# BrowserslistError: Unknown version 67 of android

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-library, angular-cli-v8

I have created one angular library using `angular 8 and CLI 8`. I am trying to build the library, but I am getting the error.

```
ng build <lib-name>
```

I have gone through some questions posted related to this error, most of them say remove `node_modules` and reinstall them. I tried this solution but still, I am getting the following error.

**[Browserslist] Could not parse package.json. Ignoring it.**

```
ERROR: Unknown version 67 of android
Unknown version 67 of android
BrowserslistError: Unknown version 67 of android
        at Function.select (C:\Users\kaukhare\github\ngx-group-by-alphabates\node_modules\ng-packagr\node_modules\autoprefixer\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:924:17)
        at C:\Users\kaukhare\github\ngx-group-by-alphabates\node_modules\ng-packagr\node_modules\autoprefixer\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:252:33
        at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
        at resolve (C:\Users\kaukhare\github\ngx-group-by-alphabates\node_modules\ng-packagr\node_modules\autoprefixer\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:234:18)
        at browserslist (C:\Users\kaukhare\github\ngx-group-by-alphabates\node_modules\ng-packagr\node_modules\autoprefixer\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:353:16)
        at Browsers.parse (C:\Users\kaukhare\github\ngx-group-by-alphabates\node_modules\ng-packagr\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:66:12)
        at new Browsers (C:\Users\kaukhare\github\ngx-group-by-alphabates\node_modules\ng-packagr\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:48:26)
        at loadPrefixes (C:\Users\kaukhare\github\ngx-group-by-alphabates\node_modules\ng-packagr\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:101:20)
        at plugin (C:\Users\kaukhare\github\ngx-group-by-alphabates\node_modules\ng-packagr\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:112:20)
        at LazyResult.run (C:\Users\kaukhare\github\ngx-group-by-alphabates\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:295:14)
        at LazyResult.sync (C:\Users\kaukhare\github\ngx-group-by-alphabates\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:281:26)
        at LazyResult.warnings (C:\Users\kaukhare\github\ngx-group-by-alphabates\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:85:17)
        at StylesheetProcessor.process (C:\Users\kaukhare\github\ngx-group-by-alphabates\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ng-v5\entry-point\resources\stylesheet-processor.js:47:16)
        at Object.readResource (C:\Users\kaukhare\github\ngx-group-by-alphabates\node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ts\cache-compiler-host.js:73:57)
        at TsCompilerAotCompilerTypeCheckHostAdapter.loadResource (C:\Users\kaukhare\github\ngx-group-by-alphabates\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\compiler_host.js:495:37)
        at Object.get (C:\Users\kaukhare\github\ngx-group-by-alphabates\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:26490:94)
```

What can be the issue? Is this error is due to `autoprefixer`? What should I do to solve this issue?

**package-lock.json**

```
"ng-packagr": {
      "version": "5.5.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ng-packagr/-/ng-packagr-5.5.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-GT6QK5WAirQwALdeJPiXdgRd5PzRqcknb/C/G+cCDEbUFri4oGVmns2Nl4I0FGg/cRn6nXTxRiUunOSqZ3Lehw==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "ajv": "^6.10.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^9.6.0",
        "browserslist": "^4.0.0"
},
    "autoprefixer": {
      "version": "9.5.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/autoprefixer/-/autoprefixer-9.5.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-KJSzkStUl3wP0D5sdMlP82Q52JLy5+atf2MHAre48+ckWkXgixmfHyWmA77wFDy6jTHU6mIgXv6hAQ2mf1PjJQ==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "browserslist": "^4.5.4",
        "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30000957",
        "normalize-range": "^0.1.2",
        "num2fraction": "^1.2.2",
        "postcss": "^7.0.14",
        "postcss-value-parser": "^3.3.1"
      }
```

Answer (score 150, accepted):

The thing that solved it for me was running

```sh
npx browserslist --update-db
```

in project root. This made changes to `package-lock.json` updating versions of `caniuse-lite`.

To give some context, I landed on this question because I was getting this error:

```sh
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
ERROR: Unknown version 80 of android
An unhandled exception occurred: Unknown version 80 of android
```

after I upgraded angular from 9.x.x to 10.x.x.
I was getting this error both on my dev machine and in CI, so removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` was not really an option.

Comment: This answer solved the same issue after Angular update. Nice!

Comment: This should be the right answer. Works for me.

Comment: @ihor, I'm facing the exact issue with my library also. But this solution is not working. I'm still getting the same version 67 android error. Please help.

Comment: This solution fixed the error "Unknown version 95 of android" when build, after update from ng 13.1.1 to 13.2.5

Comment: This also fixed my issue in an upgrade to Angular 13, thank you. I also encountered an error running ``` npx browserslist ``` as I use a shrinkwrap rather than package lock. If anyone else gets this error try running ``` npx browserslist@latest --update-db ```

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer, it helped me to solve the problem with "Unkown version xx of android" when upgrading to Angular 14. But I also had to delete the node_modules folder!

Comment: Worked for me when I got 'BrowserslistError: Unknown version 101 of android'.

Comment: had to downgrade a node version since build server did not like package-lock v2, and after i got this issue with a different version. but fixed it.

Comment: This fixed my issue going from Angular 14 to 15

Answer (score 12):

I'm seeing this too... like you, deleting node_modules and re-running npm install did not work.

What did work, however, was deleting node_modules AND deleting package-lock.json, and then running npm i.

Try that...

Andrew

Comment: Tried. But same issue.

Comment: I also had to make sure I had the latest @angular-devkit...

    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.801.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "^0.801.3",

.. in my package.json. Once I fixed that, wiped node_modules, it worked.

Comment: Tried this one as well. But same issue.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare, I'm facing the exact issues. How did you solve this error. Please help. I'm stuck since last 4 days.

Comment: @Tanzeel Accepted answer is the one. Are you facing an issue with the local machine after doing changes? Have you tried removing node_modules after updating `browserslist`.

Comment: This worked for me too after upgrading Angular, but since I'm using yarn, I had to delete `yarn.lock`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This might be too late, but I'm gonna post how I solved the issue, because I ran into it very recently (late Feb. 2022), and I followed a different approach that resulted in minimal changes to my project.
I had a similar issue with a project downloaded from StackBlitz, but in my case the unknown version of `android` was 97 instead of 67 or 80.
The `browserslist` database was up to date, deleting the `node_modules` directory and running `npm install` did not change anything (checked by using a comparison tool), updating the project's dependencies caused even more trouble, and so did deleting `package-lock.json`.

What worked in my case was specifying 98 as the target version of `android` (instead of 97) in `.browserslistrc` in the project's root directory (I actually had to create that file, as it didn't exist).

This is how I found out that version 98 works:
I first temporarily edited the code where the exception occurred (in `node_modules\browserslist\index.js`). Right before the line that throws the exception, I inserted this statement:

```
if (name === 'android') {
  return arguments.callee(context, name, (version - 1).toString())
}
```

to find the largest number less than 97 that is accepted. Then I ran `npx browserslist` and found that version to be 4.
Dissatisfied, I tried larger version numbers by replacing the above snippet with this one:

```
if (name === 'android' && Number(version) < 200) {
  return arguments.callee(context, name, (Number(version) + 1).toString())
}
```

and fortunately, 98 worked (verified by running `npx browserslist` again).
So I undid my changes to the code, grabbed that output from `npx browserslist`, and saved it in `.browserslistrc` (I also had to exclude `safari` due to another bug).
The `ng build` command then proceeded successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1.Deleting the entire node_modules directory.

2.Deleting package-lock.json from the root directory.

3.Making sure the latest @angular-devkit projects were referenced in package.json:

"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.801.3", "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "^0.801.3".

4.Close and reopen cmd window.

Running npm install.

Comment: @kaustubh-khare Are you change your package.json file with versions that I mentioned above? which version of angular and angular-cli you use?

Comment: Yes, I already tried this as well. If you check all answers and comments, then you will find your solution was already mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Can be caused by outdated babel. Try update babel using `npx babel-upgrade --write` and then `npx browserslist@latest --update-db`.

Answer (score 1):

I updated all the npm packages and the error went away.

Comment: after updating all npm packages, try running --- npm install --- again, maybe it helps to brings some ^-version-packages up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR;
Your `.browserslistrc` entries might be invalid, or suddenly not understood by some of your packages. Try to remove/replace them.

I encountered this after installing
`@angular-architects/module-federation` on an Angular project.
My existing `.browserslistrc` was:

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

Somehow after the above package got installed, the following error showed up :
`BrowserslistError: Unknown version 103 of android`

Just commented out my `.browserslistrc` entries, and got rid of this.
No idea why a package installation would cause this

Answer (score -7):

Try to modify **\node_modules\ng-packagr\node_modules\autoprefixer\node_modules\browserslist\index.js** at row **924** as follow:

```
if (alias) {
      version = alias
    } else if (context.ignoreUnknownVersions) {
      return []
    } else {
      throw new BrowserslistError(
        'Unknown version ' + version + ' of ' + name)
    }
```

in

```
if (alias) {
      version = alias
    } else if (context.ignoreUnknownVersions) {
      return []
    } else {
      return []
    }
```

I hope help you... this is dirty solution...

Comment: This worked. Can I pass `ignoreUnknownVersions : true` from somewhere ?

Comment: Could you please add a little bit more context and explanation as to what the solution actually does and why this would be a valid solution?

Comment: This worked. But -4 downvotes is a big-red flag. This is the only solution that is working for me but this is dirty. What to do. :-(