# Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated - Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem when run app dotnet-core with template angular
I got this error:

```
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run the following command: `npm update`fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run the following command: `npm update`
```

I try run `npm update` but it's not working and I don't get any message when I run that command.

All version

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.5
Node: 14.4.0
DotNet: 3.1.201
```

Package version:

[image]

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271798/browserslist-caniuse-lite-is-outdated-please-run-next-command-npm-update-cani),and maybe you can try what `Scott Kuhl` says,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using `react` instead of `angular` and I've faced the same issue.

According [`browserlist` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserslist#browsers-data-updating), in order to fix, run:

```
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
```

Comment: Is there anyway to disable this behaviour?