# Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run: npx browserslist@latest --update-db NextJS

Tags: next.js

When I run my NextJs program this error always pops up

```
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
```

So then I run npx browserslist@latest --update-db in the shell:

```
npx: installed 6 in 1.905s
Current version: 1.0.30001179
New version:     1.0.30001179
Removing old caniuse-lite from lock file
Installing new caniuse-lite version
$ npm install caniuse-lite
Cleaning package.json dependencies from caniuse-lite
$ npm uninstall caniuse-lite
caniuse-lite has been successfully updated

No target browser changes
```

And the I when I run my Next program again, the same error occurs. This started happening to me yesterday. I just used npx create-next-app and the npm run dev.

Comment: Related [Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55271798/1870780)?

Comment: I have the same issue, it happens today but he related issue didn't resolve :(

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**

The new version (10.0.6) has been released few moments ago. No warnings present.

---

This is a falsy warning in current Next.js version (10.0.5).

It's already solved in canary version, which is a base for the next stable version. You can install it (`npm install next@canary` or `yarn add next@canary`) and make sure there are no warnings.

Since canary version is not recommended for using in production, you can continue working in 10.0.5 without any side effects. The warning will disappear after new stable version release.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue by running

> npm upgrade