# How to fix npm vulnerabilities? I tried two methods, problems persist

Tags: reactjs, npm-audit

I am making a React app.

I npm installed bootstrap, vulnerabilities popped up afterwards.

Here is an example of two items from npm audit
[image]

What I tried:

1. I installed and ran npm-check-updates, which updated a few modules, but the problems persist.
2. I have tried to update the individual packages listed in npm audit, but not all 'instances'? of that package get updated on my machine. Example below.
   All browserslist packages are >=4.16.5 except the one of the last line. npm update browserslist is not working on it.

this is npm list browserslist
[image]

Comment: The most important information is missing in your question :
the full **`package.json`**.

Answer (score 0):

This command will resolve most of the conflicts

```
npm audit fix
```

Comment: beware .. especially with the `--force` parameter where it might implement breaking changes and the app might stop working

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json / yarn.lock`.

Now, run `yarn` if you use yarn

OR

`npm i` if you use NPM. It should fix.

If something goes wrong - NPM will tell you to run `npm audit fix`

Comment: I have tried deleting package-lock before to no avail.

What just worked is going into package-lock, manually finding all instances of a package, say, browserslist, and making sure it's version is set to the newest version.

Then npm ci to reinstall all modules from package-locked.

This was a pain in the ass to do for all the packages and I don't know if there was a better way. No other methods seemed to work...

Let me know what your thoughts are on this.

Comment: `npx browserslist@latest --update-db`

This command worked for me, I aslo got the same error.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271798/browserslist-caniuse-lite-is-outdated-please-run-next-command-npm-update-cani

Answer (score 0):

What just worked is going into package-lock, manually finding all instances of a package, say, browserslist, and making sure it's version is set to the newest version.

Then npm ci to reinstall all modules from package-locked.

This was a pain in the ass to do for all the packages and I don't know if there was a better way. No other methods seemed to work...

Let me know what your thoughts are on this.