# caniuse-lite is outdated will not go away after updating browserlist

Tags: browser, ember.js, ember-cli, caniuse

I'm working on fixing build warnings in my Ember.js application currently, and one I get is this

```
[Babel: @ember/test-helpers > applyPatches]Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
```

However running that command provides this output:

```
npx: installed 6 in 2.566s
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
Latest version:     1.0.30001265
Installed version:  none
Removing old caniuse-lite from lock file
Installing new caniuse-lite version
$ yarn add -W caniuse-lite
Cleaning package.json dependencies from caniuse-lite
$ yarn remove -W caniuse-lite
caniuse-lite has been successfully updated
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
```

And the warning never goes away. I have tried about every applicable solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271798/browserslist-caniuse-lite-is-outdated-please-run-next-command-npm-update-cani). This seemed to be the main one to help, but has not for me

```
npm --depth 20 update --save caniuse-lite browserslist
```

I am not using Visual Studio and have tried blowing away all node modules and still nothing. Is there any known issue around this or way to fix it?

Comment: potentially related to: https://github.com/babel/ember-cli-babel/issues/417 ?