# Configuration Of React J Project

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM7zV.png)

Please go through attached document , as I have tried “npx browserslist@latest --update-db” ample of times to configure my react project but still occurred same issue , I have also changed node and browser versions but its not working ,so may i please know solution for this issue.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, generally you should search for your answers before you ask, your solution is here, try use all methods mentions there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271798/browserslist-caniuse-lite-is-outdated-please-run-next-command-npm-update-cani

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: when i run my project i got error which mentioned in above screenshot , firstly I have executed my project on node 16.15.0  after that installed node 12.22.11 ,So as to resolve this issue but it did not help me , pls let me knw how to fix this issue